# I need some help Change this code to dictionary expression

Tags: python

```
fruit_chart = [[1, "apple", "6"], 
               [2, "orange", "5"],
               [3, "melon", "3"],
               [4, "lemon", "5"],
               [5, "grape", "5"]]

fruit_chart_dictionary = {}
for ranking, title, level in fruit_chart:
    fruit_chart_dictionary.update({ranking: [title, level]})

print(fruit_chart_dictionary)
```

How can i Change this code to dictionary expression??

Comment: What's a "dictionary expression?"

Comment: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension#pythondict

Comment: It would be very helpful to us if you could explain what language or application this is written in, so you get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension like so

```
>>> {rank: [title, level] for rank, title, level in fruit_chart}
{1: ['apple', '6'], 2: ['orange', '5'], 3: ['melon', '3'], 4: ['lemon', '5'], 5: ['grape', '5']}
```

Comment: So you are assuming "dictionary expression" == "dictionary comprehension". I have gotten downvoted for answering questions that were imprecisely asked and thus downvoted making what I thought were reasonable guesses and even stating what my assumptions were.

Comment: @Booboo I use personal judgement to decide if I think I understand what people are asking, and try to answer that question appropriately. If I misunderstood the question they are free to clarify their question and I can edit my answer accordingly. People upvote and downvote for various reasons, which they are free to do as they see fit. In this particular case I feel the question showed a clear enough attempt at what they were trying to achieve so I thought their effort warranted an attempt at answering their question.

Comment: @CoryKramer I happen to agree with you 100%.